# Проблема ошибки 504 на nginx с использованием GuzzleHttp (+ Symfony 4)

Tags: nginx, curl, symfony, timeout

Имеется агрегатор информации, подтягивающий определенную информацию с нескольких сервисов внутри нашей сети с использованием GuzzleHttp. Иногда возникают ситуации, что какой-либо из сервисом падает и не отвечает на протяжении таймаута. Если таких запросов копится штук 10, то у всех клиентов страницы начинают прогружаться с большими задержками (я молчу об AJAX запросах, которых выполняется порядка 7-8 штук при загрузке каждой страницы) и проблема распространяется на все хосты, запущенные в рамках этого nginx сервера (на одной вмке установлено 2 хоста и они оба отваливаются, как только один из сервисов внутри нашей сети перестает слать ответы). Есть ощущение, что выстраивается какая-та очередь из этих таймаутных запросов и они не дают исполниться другим, пока не пройдет время таймаута. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему? Могу приложить логи ошибок nginx, но это вряд ли даст какую-то картину:

```
2019/12/30 14:45:20 [error] 27491#27491: *73 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.232.165.65, server: , request: "POST /abonent_info/ajax_qoe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "здесьхост", referrer: "https://здесьхост/abonent_info/?num_contract=101154815+&type_contract=1"
2019/12/30 14:47:37 [error] 27492#27492: *157 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.232.165.65, server: , request: "POST /abonent_info/ajax_qoe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "здесьхост", referrer: "https://здесьхост/abonent_info/?num_contract=89887923131"
2019/12/30 14:47:38 [error] 27496#27496: *167 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.232.165.65, server: , request: "POST /abonent_info/ajax_qoe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "здесьхост", referrer: "https://здесьхост/abonent_info/?num_contract=89887923131"
```

Этот симптом распространяется и на другие запросы в случае, когда какой-либо сервис перестает отвечать:

```
2019/12/30 14:53:50 [error] 27506#27506: *414 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.232.165.65, server: , request: "POST /abonent_info/ajax_locator HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "здесьхост", referrer: "https://здесьхост/abonent_info/?num_contract=101146257&type_contract=1"
2019/12/30 15:04:00 [error] 27495#27495: *815 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.232.165.65, server: , request: "GET /abonent_info/?num_contract=89898638859&type_contract=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock", host: "здесьхост", referrer: "https://здесьхост/abonent_info/?num_contract=89898638859"
```

Не думаю, что снижение/увеличение времени таймаута будет выходом. Важно, чтобы как можно больше запросов обрабатывалось одновременно.

Comment: Выносите запросы на фронт, где вы можете сделать параллельно Ajax запросы.  `я молчу об AJAX запросах, которых выполняется порядка 7-8 штук при загрузке каждой страницы`   это не аякс запросы, строго  говоря. 

Формировать на бэке страницу зависящую от предварительно получаемых данных по http вероятно не самое лучшее архитектурное решение.

Comment: Используйте очереди для агрегации информации из нескольких источников. Отдельное задание на каждый источник.

Comment: @zalex вы возможно не совсем правильно поняли. Пользователь получает страницу, а затем на сервер отправляется несколько запросов для параллельной загрузки данных с других серверов (напрямую от клиента на эти сервера мы не можем отправлять запросы, т.к. во-первых, используются токены для авторизации на множестве сервисов, а во-вторых сами пользователи могут обращаться как со внутренней сети, так и внешней; давать возможность ручной авторизации пользователям довольно трудоемкий процесс для нас по разным причинам, включая случай с внутренней/внешней сетью).

Comment: @Romka как-то читал про очереди в rabbitmq, но так и не догнал как ими правильно пользоваться. Вообще, просто хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы множественные таймаутные запросы не ложили весь сервер целиком. Может есть что-то в связке с Symfony 4, с описанными подробностями?

Comment: https://github.com/jorge07/symfony-4-es-cqrs-boilerplate немного больше, чем Вы просите, - но с работающим примером, недавно сам поднимал / рассматривал.